# eslint ignores one specific file and doesn't show any warnings or errors

Tags: eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint, eslintrc, prettier-eslint

I'm making React/TS project with eslint and prettier.
I installed and set up eslint and prettier following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cchqeWY0Nak&t&ab_channel=CodingGarden).
But eslint doesn't work in one specific file and logs the following in the VSCode output:

```
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslintrc:cascading-config-array-factory Load config files for C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer.
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslintrc:cascading-config-array-factory Cache hit: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer.
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslint:cli-engine Lint C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslint:linter Linting code for C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx (pass 1)
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslint:linter Verify
2023-10-12T20:19:08.187Z eslint:linter With ConfigArray: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.188Z eslint:linter Parsing: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.211Z eslint:linter Parsing successful: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.211Z eslint:linter Scope analysis: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.211Z eslint:linter Scope analysis successful: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter An error occurred while traversing
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter Filename: C:\Projects\swift-learner\src\components\WordTrainer\WordTrainer.tsx
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter Line: 1
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter Parser Options: {
  ecmaVersion: 'latest',
  ecmaFeatures: {
    globalReturn: false,
    jsx: true,
    generators: false,
    objectLiteralDuplicateProperties: false
  },
  sourceType: 'module',
  project: './tsconfig.json'
}
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter Parser Path: C:\Projects\swift-learner\node_modules\@typescript-eslint\parser\dist\index.js
2023-10-12T20:19:08.273Z eslint:linter Settings: {
  'import/resolver': {
    alias: { map: [Array], extensions: [Array] },
    alwaysTryTypes: true,
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    node: { extensions: [Array] }
  },
  'import/parsers': { '@typescript-eslint/parser': [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts' ] },
  react: { version: 'detect', pragma: 'React' },
  'import/ignore': [ 'node_modules', '\\.(coffee|scss|css|less|hbs|svg|json|mjs)$' ],
  'import/extensions': [ '.js', '.mjs', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts' ],
  'import/external-module-folders': [ 'node_modules', 'node_modules/@types' ],
  propWrapperFunctions: [ 'forbidExtraProps', 'exact', 'Object.freeze' ],
  'import/core-modules': []
}
[Error - 11:19:08 PM] An unexpected error occurred:
[Error - 11:19:08 PM] Error: Missing visitor keys for 'AsExpression'.
    at rr (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:418)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12706)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12755)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12675)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12755)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12675)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12755)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12755)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12675)
    at CM (file:///C:/Projects/swift-learner/node_modules/prettier/plugins/flow.mjs:21:12755)
```

When I `run npm lint` it throws the same error. I googled an haven't found anything. Could anybody tell me what's wrong?

prettier:

```
const config = {
  trailingComma: 'all',
  tabWidth: 2,
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  jsxSingleQuote: true,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
};

module.exports = config;
```

eslint:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      env: {
        node: true,
      },
      files: ['.eslintrc.cjs'],
      parserOptions: {
        sourceType: 'script',
      },
    },
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'react', 'prettier', 'react-hooks', 'import'],
  ignorePatterns: ['vite.config.ts'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    'arrow-body-style': 'off', // ["error", "as-needed"]
    'prefer-arrow-callback': 'off',
    semi: ['error', 'always'],
    'linebreak-style': ['error', 'windows'],
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'jsx-quotes': ['error', 'prefer-single'],
    quotes: ['error', 'single'],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    indent: ['error', 2],
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'react/function-component-definition': [
      2,
      {
        namedComponents: 'arrow-function',
        unnamedComponents: 'arrow-function',
      },
    ],
    'import/no-unresolved': 'error',
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [['@', './src']],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
      alwaysTryTypes: true,
      project: './tsconfig.json',
    },
    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    react: {
      version: 'detect',
    },
  },
};
```